# What is NCover and how does it relate to NUnit?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, ncover

I'm writing unit tests using NUnit.Framework for a project I have up live. I have read few things about Ncover and it looks like an alternative of NUnit. Could someone please explain what it really is and what it does or post a link where I could find my answer.

Answer (score 0):

NCover is a code-coverage tool that allows you to assess how much of your source code is "covered" by unit tests.  The idea is that while you're running your unit tests with nUnit, nCover will be operating in the background, keeping track of each line of code that's being executed.  After the tests are finished, nCover will show a visual report showing exactly which parts of your source code are and are not covered by existing unit tests.

It's a tool to help you determine if you have any functionality that isn't assessed by unit tests.  While it's not perfect, it does give a good visual representation if you're missing out on some potential tests.

Comment: So NCover is a software which will run in the background to check this?

Comment: @Yagzii yes, NCover is meant to work in conjunction with NUnit